# Localize tags inside of HTML in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, localization, resources

I am just wondering if it is possible to reference somehow to languages resources within of HTML

I have this HTML i.e.

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Requsition.RequisitionProductLines).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add()
           .Encoded(false)
           .Sanitized(false)
           .SetWidth(20)
           .Titled("Actions")
           .Css("hidden-xs") //hide on phones
           .RenderValueAs(x =>
            @<b>
                <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus glyphiconPlusBtn" style="float:left;" href="@Url.Content("~/Requisition/Product/Delete/" + x.ProductUID)"
                   data-placement="right" data-original-title="Click here to delete this Product." data-toggle="tooltip"></a>

            </b>);
        columns.Add(x => x.Product.Name)
                     .Titled("Name")
                     .SetWidth(130);
```

and for another hand **Resources** files under `Properties` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found how I can get resources.

1) At the top of file add

> @using YourModelEntities.Properties

Where **YourModelEntities** is your project where you keep translated resources.
And **Properties** is a folder where you keep your `Resource.de-DE.resx` files.

2) Add refernce where you need it i.e.

@YourModelEntities.Properties.Resource.Products

Thats all!